# Catalyst Control Center host application has stopped working...

Tags: windows-vista, amd-catalyst

I just had to use system restore because of a nasty virus. Now I have everything running nicely again except that I keep getting a message saying that (read topic)  I can't even open the control center to try and see what the problem is. I am using Vista 64 and ATI Radeon 3200 HD graphics. Note, nothing about the way in which the monitor works is effected. Just the ability to open the control center itself.

Here is the error message

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: ccc.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 469cdc9c
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4d8c2144
  Problem Signature 07: 20c7
  Problem Signature 08: 143
  Problem Signature 09: N3CTRYE2KN3C34SGL4ZQYRBFTE4M13NB
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
```